# Submit a form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I currently have an issue submitting form to the server. When I click on the Submit button, all the fields in the form get submitted but when I use `$('#form3').submit()`, just one field is submitted.

Find below my code to automatically submit  the form on countdown equal to zero.

```
var countdown = 10000;//expire * 60 * 1000;
var timerId = setInterval(function(){
    countdown -= 1000;
    var min = Math.floor(countdown / (60 * 1000));
    var sec = Math.floor((countdown - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);  //correct
    if (countdown <= 0) {
        $('#form3').submit();
        alert("Time Up!");
        clearInterval(timerId);
        return false;
    }else {
        $("#showtime").html(min + " Min : " + sec + " Sec");
    }
}, 1000); //1000ms. = 1sec.
```

The form markup

```
<form class="form-validation" id="form3" action="{{url('submit-form')}}" method="POST">       

{{csrf_field()}}

    <fieldset class="step" id="validation-step1">
        <h6 class="form-wizard-title text-semibold">
            Teacher's Instructions
            <small class="display-block">Select the correct option.</small>
        </h6>

        <div class="row">
            <p class="lead" style="margin-left: 60px;">{{@$question->question}}</p>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p class="lead">Please, read the instructions carefully before you start.</p>
                    <br>

                    <input type="hidden" name="exam" value="{{@$exam->id}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

@php $i = 2; $sn=1; @endphp
@foreach(@$questions as $question)

    @php 
        $options = collect([$question->option1, $question->option2, $question->option3, $question->option4, $question->option5])->shuffle(); 
    @endphp
    <fieldset class="step" id="validation-step{{@$i++}}">
        <h6 class="form-wizard-title text-semibold">
            <span class="form-wizard-count">{{@$sn++}}</span>
            Question 
            <small class="display-block">Select the correct answer to the question.</small>
        </h6>

        <div class="row">
            <p class="lead" style="margin-left: 60px;">{{@$question->question}}</p>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 40px;">
                        @foreach($options as $option)
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label class="lead">
                                    <input type="radio" value="{{@$option}}" name="question[{{@$question->id}}]" class="">
                                    {{@$option}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                    @if(@$question->image)
                        <img src="{{@$question->image}}" class="" style="width: 80%; height: 60%; border: 1px solid black; margin: 20px;">
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
@endforeach

    <div class="form-wizard-actions">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="validation-back"    type="reset">Back</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="validation-next" type="submit">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the markup for the form?

Comment: @KLP I have added the markup to the question

Comment: Which field gets submitted when you use `$('#form3').submit()`?

Comment: @MattU most time, just the _token field. Sometimes, the exam field if not radios were selected and only one radio if more answers are selected. This doesn't happen when I submit manually.

Answer (score 1):

you can check again form id, maybe it duplicated with another form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked that already and no duplicate form with same ID.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you show the log of $("#form3")object before you submit the form. 
Because at the moment you click on the button, maybe every elements of your page and your form is ready but it's not ready when your code executes!

```
if (countdown <= 0) {
    console.log($('#form3')); // to see the object form is ready or not 
    console.log($("#form3").serialize()); // to see what data inside the form at that time
    return false; // to see the log
    //$('#form3').submit();
    //alert("Time Up!");
    //clearInterval(timerId);
    //return false;
}
```

Comment: It returned only the _token value

Comment: That means your form is not ready when the code executes! Or there's something wrong with HTML code after render.
Could you show the form HTML at that time 
console.log('#form3').html()

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: console.log($('#form3').html());

Comment: All items (text field and radios) have the disabled attribute

Comment: Ok, that means your object $("#form3") is not the object you see on screen. 
So, please insert the div contains the form and named id="the-new-container"

**<div id="the-new-container"><form class="the-form"></form></div>** 

And then, use query **$("#the-div-container .the-form").submit()** instead

Comment: All items (text field and radios) have the disabled attribute when it showed in the console

Comment: Yup! So just remove the disabled attribute then you got the data from the form!

Comment: Thanks, you are a life saver. The Form-Wizard library was the one interfering.